# $f$ is cont. at $c$ iff $\lim f(x) = f(c)$ as $x\to c$ for $x\in {\Bbb Q}$ and $\lim f(x) = f(c)$ as $x\to c$ for $ x\in{\Bbb R}\backslash{\Bbb Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

1. Let $f:{\Bbb R}\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $c\in{\Bbb R}$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to c,x\in{\Bbb Q}}f(x) = f(c)$ and $\lim_{x\to c,x\in{\Bbb R}\backslash{\Bbb Q}}f(x) = f(c)$.

My working:
proving forward: i know that $0<|x-c|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ then I'm unsure of how to continue with the proof. Proving backward seems more difficult.
I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Prove the following

**Lemma:** For a real function $\;f\;$, we have that for $\;x_0\in\;$ domain of $\;f\;$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L\iff\;\text{ both}\;\;\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{x\to x_0\,,\,x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)&=L\\{}\\\lim\limits_{x\to x_0\,,\,x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q}f(x)&=L\end{cases}$$

For the proof  you now can for example use the sequential definition of limit: take $\;\{x_n\}\;$ s.t. $\;x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x_0\;$ and form from this sequence two complementary subsequences: one rational and the other one irrational (if there's a finite number of either then we're done already).

**Added on request:**

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\text{Suppose $\;f\;$ is continuous at }\;\;c\implies \lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)\iff \forall\,\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;s.t.\;\\
&x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}c\;,\;f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(c)\iff \text{ both}\;\;\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{x\to c\,,\,x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)&=f(c)\\{}\\\lim\limits_{x\to c\,,\,x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q}f(x)&=f(c)\end{cases}\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;\text{Suppose now that the condition on the limits is fulfilled, then by the above lemma}\\
&\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)\;\;\text{so $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;c\;$ and we're done!}\end{align*}$$

Comment: sorry I don't really get you. Do you mean like {xn}->a we have f(xn)->f(a), where a is a rational number, etc?

Comment: Yes, that's the sequential definition of continuity, but with $\;a\;$ **any** number, not only rational.

Comment: I get what you mean. But the sequential definition requires ALL sequences to be satisfied. How do we do it? Or do you have any working? It will be clearer that way. Thanks!:)

Comment: @eee, read my added stuff to my answer.

Comment: Thanks I get it. If we were to solve it by the epsilon-delta definition method, how would the working turn out? :)